# Windows-Installer using Installshield: how to match ALLUSERS setting with Env Vars

Tags: windows-installer, environment-variables, installshield

I am making an MSI based installation package with Installshield Express 2011.

I like to set the `ALLUSERS` field to `2`, which means that a per-machine installation is attempted but if that is not possible then a per-user installation is performed.

But my package must also create some environment variables which have to be set as either System or User variables.  These do not seem to be affected by the `ALLUSERS` field, such that if a per-user installation is being performed then the installer may try to set a System environment variable which would be inappropriate/prohibited for a per-user installation.

Is there way in Installshield to have the enviornment variables set according to whether it is a per-user or per-machine installation?

One solution would be to have `ALLUSERS` set to `""` which would cause every installation to be per-user, however this is not suitable for small business environments where different staff may log on and expect to be able to use the product.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet from the MSDN documentation 
"If the package can be installed per-user or per-machine, create two components: (1) a per-user component with the Environment table entries authored for user settings, and (2) a per-machine component with the Environment table authored for computer settings. Condition the installation of this component using the Privileged property."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368369(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

In the Install Shield Project under the **3 Configure the target System** there is step named **Enviroment Variables**

[image]